# Better use one long query or multiple ones?

Tags: php, mysql, function

i have this simple function:

```
$password = 'userinput';
$username = 'userinput02';

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'root', '');
$stmt = $bdd->prepare('SELECT username, hash, someinfo, someotherinfo FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($username));
$reponse = $stmt->fetch();

if($reponse['username'])
{
    if(password_verify($password, $reponse['hash']))
    {
       UseSomeInfo();
       echo 'good password';
    }
}
```

and i'm wondering if only selecting the username,
wait for 1st statement to be confirmed,
then selecting the hash isn't a more efficiant/standard/secure way to do the same thing.

Comment: For this use case yes i would use one query - no need to use two

Comment: consider that each query() call has a cost - if you KNOW you're going to need extra data later, might as well fetch it in the initial query. The extra cost of adding a few extra fields that may no be there is FAR smaller than the cost of setting up and running two separate queries. If the user doesn't exist, then you've sent a few extra bytes over the wire. If the user does exist, you've already got everything you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the fact that your query will not return any results if there is no match. Therefore, the "extra" columns aren't going to affect the amount of data that must be returned/read from the table if there is no match.

However, if there is a match, you do want the "extra" columns. So, no reason to suffer the overhead of an additional query.

In actuality, there is some miniscule overhead with parsing and validating the extra columns, but it won't be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's more efficient to return additional columns from the same row, using one query, than it is to execute a second query to return columns from the same row.

On the server side, there's the overhead of receiving the SQL text, parsing it, determining that the statement is syntactically correct, verifying that the statement is semantically correct (e.g. all identifiers are valid, user has appropriate privileges on objects), preparing an execution plan, and then actually executing the plan (obtaining locks, accessing rows, materializing the resultset), returning the resultset to the caller.

Given a suitable index on the `username` column, the time for the actual "execution" of the prepared plan will be a small fraction of the overall server time.

The actual execution time for this query would be the lion's share of the server elapsed time only if there weren't a suitable index, and MySQL had to do a full scan of the table, or there were multiple sessions competing for locks on the table. A second query of the same form would exhibit the same performance characteristics.

And on the client side, there's overhead of allocating resources, forming the SQL text to be sent to the server, and receiving and processing the returned resultset.

In the OP example code, it's very clear that there would be a performance penalty for breaking the existing query into two separate queries.